# Retrieving 'RichTextData' from db and posting it to html page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

How to retrieve RichTextData from Microsoft MySQL server and post it to HTML page without modifying the original data.

can you please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: no i don't know how to post it to a HTML page.i know how to retrieve it.the data is in var binary format.

Comment: The same way by which you have inserted into database.

Comment: thank you.but the thing is for example if the text is like <strong>hi</strong> then the text should be seen as hi but by what you said it is shown as <strong>hi</strong>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it in asp.net(since you tagged question with asp.net) then you can do it as follows

Take a label in your aspx page

```
<asp:Label Id="label1" runat="server" />
```

In code behind fetch the data you want to post and assign it to label

```
label1.text="your value from database";
```

**Update:**

Take a Literal in your aspx page

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

In code behind fetch the data you want to post and assign it to Literal

```
Literal1.Text = " <strong>hi</strong>";
```

Comment: thank you.but the thing is for example if the text is like <strong>hi</strong> then the text should be seen as **hi** but by what you said it is shown as <strong>hi</strong> .